# Matrix differentiation with vector variables on either side of matrix

Tags: matrices, functions, derivatives

Is there a trick to matrix differentiation for some function $\nabla_xf(x)$ where $f(x)=x^TAx$ for example and $x$ is just a variable of vectors $x=[x_1 \;x_2,...,\:x_n]^{T}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ ? I know that for $Ax$ it's just $A$ but I'm wondering how to account for the fact that we have $x$ on both sides? Does the product rule apply? How would it even work here?

Answer (score 1):

We can use this property:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f & = x^TAy = y^TA^Tx \\
df &= dx^T(Ay) + (x^TA)dy = dy^T(A^Tx) + (y^TA^T)dx\\
& = (x^TA)dy + (y^TA^T)dx \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now for your expression, we just put $x=y$ and we differentiate

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g & = x^TAx \\
dg &= (x^TA)dx + (x^TA^T)dx\\
& = x^T(A + A^T)dx \\
\frac{dg}{dx} &= x^T(A + A^T)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Depending on your preferred [Layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), the derivative could be either

$$\frac{d(x^TAx)}{dx} = x^T(A + A^T)$$

or

$$\frac{d(x^TAx)}{dx} = (A + A^T)x$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Write $g(x,y) = x^TAy$, note that $f(x)=g(x,x)$, and compute $$Df(x) = D_xg(x,x) + D_yg(x,x).$$You know that $$D_xg(x,y)(v) = v^TAy\quad\mbox{and}\quad D_yg(x,y)(v)=x^TAv.$$So $$Df(x)(v) = v^TAx + x^TAv = x^TA^Tv + x^TAv = x^T(A+A^T)v = ((A+A^T)x)^Tv.$$This means that $$\nabla f(x) = (A+A^T)x,$$in view of the characterization $Df(x)(v) = (\nabla f(x))^Tv$.

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate expressions involving matrices, you can also go back to the definition of the derivative and
compute $f(x+h)$.
\begin{align*}
  f(x+h) &= (x+h)^T A (x+h) \\
  &= x^T A x + x^T A h + h^T A x + h^T A h \\
  &= f(x) + x^T A h + ( h^T A x )^T + O(\|h\|^2) \\
  &= f(x) + x^T A h + x^T A^T h + O(\|h\|^2) \\
  &= f(x) + x^T (A + A^T) h + O(\|h\|^2)
\end{align*}
The derivative of $f$ is the linear map $h \mapsto x^T (A + A^T) h$ or,
equivalently, the row vector $x^T (A + A^T)$,
or the column vector $(A^T + A) x$.